# Embed videos stored on a different computer in HTML on an Apache server

Tags: apache, video

One of my computers has an Apache/2.4.56 (Raspbian) server hosting a Web site. Some videos I've created are stored on a NAS which is on the same 192.168.1 network as the Apache server. My idea is to create a page on my site which lists the videos and allows them to be played.

The result so far is a video box containing controls but no video, and the Play button greyed out.

The (simplified) code so far looks something like this:

```
 <h1>
 <span>
 <video controls width="1000" controls>
 <source="smb:///192.168.1.13:445/GP/current/202308_15fps.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <a href="smb:///192.168.1.13:445/GP/current/202308_15fps.mp4">MP4</a>
 </video>                       
 <span class="subText"></span>
 </h1>
```

In VNC session on the Apache machine, logging in as the same user as manages Apache, the NAS is accessible, can be log onto, and the videos can be accessed and played.

What am I overlooking? Do I have to configure Apache to allow it to access files on another machine? Is the approach flawed?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not Apache but your browser refusing to let a page loaded through http (or https) access files on the local file system (`smb://...`)

If Apache can reach those files (and mount those drives) and can make the videos available through http as well (you might open up directories that are otherwise password protected to the network), then that would be an option. Or have your NAS serve them through http.